# Get custom attribute from product in ToOrderItem convert method

Tags: quoteitem, sales-order-item

I'm implementing a plugin for `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem`

```
    public function aroundConvert(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item,
        $additional = []) {
    $orderItem = $proceed($item, $additional);

    $product = $this->productFactory->create();
    $product->load($item->getProductId());

    $unitPv = 0;
    if ($product->getCustomAttribute('pv') != null) {       
        $unitPv = $product->getCustomAttribute('pv')->getValue();
    }

    $pv = $unitPv;
    $qty = $orderItem->getQty();

    // ???
    $orderItem->setData('pv', $pv); 
    $orderItem->setData('total_pv', $qty * $pv);
    return $orderItem;
}
```

This method to supposed to copy over a custom attribute (PV) from my products over to the sales order item field (PV and total PV) which I added directly to the `sales_order_item table`.

My code above is able to retrieve the PV from the products but for some reason is unable to assign the values to the ordered item. Is my syntax to assign the PV and `total_pv` to `order_sales_item` correct?

Comment: did you created 'pv, total_pv' columns on sales_order_item table? . Please verify the sales_order_item table.

Comment: The fields 'pv' and 'total_pv' are created and exists in the sales_order_item table.

Comment: $orderItem->getData('pv); 
$orderItem->getData('total_pv');

below the setData, try to print this values in logger and check whether the values are getting set or not in orderItem Object.